# How to fetch data from database, hashmap it, converti hashmap to JSONObject list and use it in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, postgresql, list, hashmap

I'm working on a java web project using (tomcat,jsp,postgres,googlemap etc.).  The postgres database table has 7 columns and one of the columns is of geography datatype.  So I retrieved the data using Hashmap and put it in an ArrayList with the following method that receives a ResultSet object.

```
  public ArrayList resultSetToArrayList(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException{

  ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
  int columns = md.getColumnCount();
  ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> dataMap = new 
  ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();

  while (rs.next()){
  HashMap row = new HashMap(columns);
        for(int i=1; i<=columns; ++i){                          
            row.put(md.getColumnName(i),rs.getObject(i));
        }
        list.add(row);
    }
  return list;
}
```

In my doGet servlet method, I have the following code to convert the arraylist to JSONObject list and then I forward the response to a jsp.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> hashmapData =  
newArrayList<HashMap<String, 
Object>>();
hashmapData = api.resultSetToArrayList(rs);//api is an instance  
                            of my APIService class that contains the method
List<JSONObject> jsonObj = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

for(HashMap<String, Object> data : hashmapData) { 
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(data);
        jsonObj.add(obj);
}
request.setAttribute("data",jsonObj);

              //Disptching request

RequestDispatcher dispatcher =
request.getRequestDispatcher("displayallobjects.jsp");

              if (dispatcher != null){
              dispatcher.forward(request, response);
              } 
  .....
   ....//rest of the code
  }
```

Everything is working and I'm able to retrieve the JSONObject List in my .jsp file through a request object in the following format:

```
  <script>
        var jsondata = '<%=request.getAttribute("data") %>'
  ....
  </script>

 [{"id":49,"location":"POINT(43.5729914065888 -79.7675657272339)", 
 "questid":3,"image":"images\/science.jpg","type":"science"}, 
 {"id":51,"location":"POINT(43.5725872088145 -79.7640466690063)", 
 "questid":5,"image":"images\/math.jpg","type":"math"}, 
 {"id":52,"location":"POINT(43.5730224986129 -79.7701406478882)", 
 "questid":2,"image":"images\/math.jpg","type":"math"}, 
 {"id":53,"location":"POINT(43.5742972577808 -79.7683811187744)", 
 "questid":1,"image":"images\/english.jpg","type":"english"}, 
 {"id":54,"location":"POINT(43.5707838318471 -79.7665357589722)", 
 "questid":9,"image":"images\/science.jpg","type":"science"}]
```

Now, I need to use this data to create markers on the map.  I just can't seem to parse this data in any way.  I tried JSON.parse(jsondata), and other relations functions available in javascript like stringify etc.  but nothing works.

How can I save the value of each item into javascript array variables, so I loop through the array and display the markers on proper locations with the right icons.?????? PLEASE HELP, I've spent so much time trying to figure this out.  Nothing is working.

What I think the problem is the format of the json object [{"":""}].  but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: What's not working about using JSON.parse? That's valid json, it should parse just fine. (I checked the validity of the json using http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: how would I use JSON.parse function to get, let`s say the image path and save it in a var called img?

Comment: var json = '<%=request.getAttribute("data") %>'   
    for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        var obj = json[i];
        alert(obj.id);
    }

Comment: when i try the above code, json.length gives me the total length of the string, 850 and loops through each character and displays "undefined" in the alert box.  I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

*********I fixed the problem*********
i just had to convert json variable back to JSON object by doing json = JSON.parse(json); to make sure that js doesn't treat it like a string. that fixed it for me and now I can get the image by looping through it with obj.image.  Thanks Ehren Murdick for taking the time to read and reply.